# How to create a custom control with both an enabled and disabled visual state and a content presenter

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, custom-controls

I'm new to making custom WPF controls so I'd really appreciate a little help and some explanation. Here's the situation:

I'm trying to make a custom control with the following traits:

- The control must have a content presenter.
- The control must have either a disabled/enabled visual state, or be tri-state, (unstarted/inprogress/finished)
- The control should if possible have support for an animation based on the state (enabled/disabled)

Ideally I'd like something that I can stack nicely like this, so any suggestions for how to do this would be appreciated.

I am using Blend 3 if anyone wants me to use VSM stuff, but I have no experience with the blend 3 extension so I'd need a little guidance and explanation if possible.  Thank you all of your time!

Answer (score 3):

In WPF it's very easy to change the appearance and behaviour of (standard)controls. In this case you can use a checkbox as a starting point.

First make a copy of the control's template:

"img43.imageshack.us/img43/1694/36338162.png"

You will see the folowing:

"img194.imageshack.us/img194/374/89409336.png"

Now group the BulletDecorator into a Grid, move then ContentPresenter to that Grid and remove the BulletDecorator and ist children.

"img9.imageshack.us/img9/7739/74247109.png"

At this point you have a checkbox like control that only has a ContentPresenter.

Now you can use the trigger tab to set is behaviour.

"http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/3675/15279262.png"

The code:

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:Microsoft_Windows_Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"
x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
x:Name="Window"
Title="MainWindow"
Width="640" Height="480" mc:Ignorable="d">

<Window.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CheckBoxFillNormal" Color="#F4F4F4"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CheckBoxStroke" Color="#8E8F8F"/>
    <Style x:Key="EmptyCheckBoxFocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Stroke="Black" StrokeDashArray="1 2" StrokeThickness="1" Margin="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="true"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="CheckRadioFocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Stroke="Black" StrokeDashArray="1 2" StrokeThickness="1" Margin="14,0,0,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="true"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="CheckBoxStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource CheckBoxFillNormal}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource CheckBoxStroke}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource EmptyCheckBoxFocusVisual}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                    <Grid x:Name="grid" Width="64.42" Height="15.96">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="13,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="grid" Value="#FF07FF00"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="grid" Value="Red"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFDD00"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="grid" Value="#FFFFF400"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="117,72,0,0" Style="{DynamicResource CheckBoxStyle1}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="CheckBox" IsThreeState="True"/>
    <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="117,91.96,0,0" Style="{DynamicResource CheckBoxStyle1}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="CheckBox" IsThreeState="True" IsChecked="{x:Null}"/>
    <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="117,111.92,0,0" Style="{DynamicResource CheckBoxStyle1}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="CheckBox" IsThreeState="True" IsChecked="True"/>
    <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="209,72,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="CheckBox" IsThreeState="True"/>
    <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="209,92.96,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="CheckBox" IsChecked="{x:Null}" IsThreeState="True"/>
    <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="CheckBox" Margin="209,111.92,0,0" IsThreeState="True" IsChecked="True"/>
</Grid>
```

Was this any help to you?

Greetings,
Carl

Comment: I'm actually already quite aware of this, tho I suppose I hadn't thought about using a checkbox control to do this.  however this is a great post that is very relevant so I'm going to go ahead and upvote, welcome to stackoverflow!